# How to find if graph G is connected with these conditions?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$. If $\deg u+\deg v+ \deg w\geq n-1$ for every three pairwise nonadjacent vertices $u,v, w$ of $G$, must $G$ be connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $G$ is connected. By the pigeonhole principle there exists some vertex $z$ such that at least two of $u,v,w$ are adjacent to $z$ and therefore are in the same connected component. Weakening the inequality to $\geq n-4$ still works, because we know $u,v,w$ are disjoint. Thus out of the $v-4$ vertices remaining, since the sum of degrees is $\geq v-3>v-4$ by the pigeonhole principle there is some vertex adjacent to two.